# Is possible to force for load armv7 library on arm64 android device as programmatically?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, arm64, armv7

I trying to load armv7 native library on my app. (device is arm64 android)
but when execute my app, i faced error message.

**couldn't find "xxxx.so"**

To solved the problem, i used these in build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
        }
    }
```

or

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"
        universalApk false
    }
}
```

As a result, these solutions are succeeded (loaded armv7 native library). But these solutions could not load arm64 native libraries. 
(because i use additional libraries (arm64).)

In summary, I use both arm64 libraries and armv7 libraries.

So, if somebody have another solutions such as programmatically specified path of library, please let me know the that.

Comment: How would you expect to transition from AArch64 state to AArch32 and back when jumping to and from library code? How would you expect the return address to persist with smaller register width, or how would you even address the parts of the address space beyond 0xffffffff?

Comment: _"I use both arm64 libraries and armv7 libraries"_ You can't. You can use armv7 libraries on an arm64 device, but then _all_ libraries must be armv7. You can't mix and match.

Comment: Thank you, i will have to use all armv7 libraries!